# Nautilus sidebar mount points have started to show

Tags: nautilus

`Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS`
`Nautilus 1:3.36.3-0ubuntu`

Nautilus has started to show mount points above the shortcuts in the sidebar. Previously I was not seeing them there. This doesn't seem to be something I can turn off. Searching this site has returned some 4 year old answers that don't quite make sense to me since the behavior seems to have changed "spontaneously". It's a nuisance since I rarely access mounts/partitions through the file manager and Nautilus places them above the shortcuts I created and use constantly. Can this be configured off somehow or am I going to need a new file manager? Suggestions?